# Find the domain of the inequation $x^2 -ax +1-2a^2 > 0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$

Tags: inequality

if $x^2 -ax +1-2a^2 > 0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$ then find the set of real values of $a$.

the book give the solution as :

since $x^2 -ax +1-2a^2 > 0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$, 
$\quad \implies \quad a^2-4(1-2a^2) < 0\quad \implies \quad -\frac{2}3<a<\frac{2}3$

but is the discriminant is smaller than $0$, then the solutions skips into the complex region. then how can the value of $a$ be such that the solutions of the inequation are complex.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding something. If a quadratic is always positive, or above the x-axis, then the discriminant is negative. This means that there are no real roots as you said.

Comment: The solution that skips into the complex region is the solution to *the equation* $x^2-ax+1-2a^2=0$, not to the inequality.

Comment: A real solution exists when $x^2 - ax + 1 - 2a^2 = 0$.  If $x^2 - ax + 1 - 2a^2 > 0$ then there are *no* real solutions.  So you *WANT* the discriminant to be negative because you do *NOT* want *ANY* real solutions.  (And if there are no real solutions you *want* the solutions to skip into the complex region... well, you don't *want* them to but you have no choice.  They skip into the region and you ignore them... but you are *happy* that there *aren't* any real solutions.)

Answer (score 1):

actuelly we get
$$x^2-2\cdot \frac{a}{2}x+\frac{a^2}{4}+1-2a^2-\frac{a^2}{4}>0$$
this is $$\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+1-\frac{9}{4}a^2>0$$

Answer (score 1):

$y_a:= x^2 - ax+ 1-2a^2$ can be thought of a parabola, which opens upward .

Completing the square gives you the vertex.

1) $y_a \gt 0$ for all $x$, the parabola does not have zeroes, i.e. does not touch or go below the $X$-axis.

$y_a$ has no zeroes: $y= x^2-ax+1-2a^2 =0$ has no real roots.

This is the case for:

$a^2 -4(1-2a^2)  \lt 0$, or

$9a^2  -4 \lt 0$, or

$(3a -2)(3a+2) \lt 0.$

One factor must be positive the other negative.

Hence : $-2/3  < a< 2/3.$

Answer (score 0):

> but if the discriminant is smaller than 0, then the solutions skips into the complex region. then how can the value of a be such that the solutions of the inequation are complex.

That is precisely what you *WANT*.

If the equation had real solutions then sometimes $x^2 -ax +1-2a^2 = 0$.  But you want it to *NEVER* equal $0$.  So you want it to have *NO* real solutions.

Okay.... that does mean it has complex solutions but you don't care about those.  You only care that $x^2 -ax +1-2a^2 > 0$.

And for that to happen the discriminant *MUST* be negative.  That is what you *WANT*.  If the discriminant were $0$ or greater then there would be real solutions which you absolutely do *NOT* want to *ever* happen.